# Pull list of domains, and list of users, search by -like givenname and -eq Surname, output to csv if exists and enabled status

Tags: powershell, csv, dns

I am a bit of a newb, self teaching myself powershell for an IAM role. I was asked for termination testing, to create a powershell script to check a list of users for their existence in a provided list of domains, and output a csv containing their Given Name, Surname, Server, Exists, Enabled, and. account ID.  Here is what I have so far. I'm fumbling on the split as each user outputted is the first, as well as setting up proper output. Any help is much appreciated!

```
$servers = ".\serverlist.txt"
$users = ".\userlist.txt"
$outfile = ".\findings.csv"

Foreach ($server in $servers) {

    Foreach ($user in $users) {

      $User = Get-ADUser -Server $server -Filter "GivenName -like '$FirstName*' -and Surname -like '$LastName*'" -properties * |select name,givenname, sn,enabled 

      If ($User -eq $Null) {$FirstName + " " + $Lastname +  "False $server"| Add-Content $outfile}
      Else {$FirstName + " " + $LastName + "True, $server" | Add-Content $outfile}     

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chris, it is not clear from your script where the $FirstName and $LastName variables come from? Are they properties of the $Users variable? it's not clear where you are importing those.

If I assume they are properties of the users variable, you could try something like this:

```
$servers = ".\serverlist.txt"
$users = ".\userlist"
$outfile = ".\findings.csv"

$results = Foreach ($server in $servers) {

    Foreach ($user in $users) {

        $FirstName = $user.FirstName
        $LastName = $user.LastName

        $User = Get-ADUser -Server $server -Filter "GivenName -like '$FirstName*' -and Surname -like '$LastName*'" -properties name,givenname, sn,enabled |Select-Object -Property name,givenname, sn,enabled 

        If(-Not($user))
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                FirstName = $FirstName
                LastName = $LastName
                Server = $server
                Present = $false
            }
        }
        Else
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                FirstName = $FirstName
                LastName = $LastName
                Server = $server
                Present = $false
            }
        }
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $outfile
```

Comment: Sorry about that! userlist.txt is where we are pulling the list of names.  I was using a split so I can search first name (-like because I can't predict for short name, long (Chris, or Christopher) I'll def try your rendition out and let you know! Much thanks!

Comment: hmm, everything looks correct on my serverlist.txt - Get-ADUser : Invalid URI: The server name ".\serverlist.txt" could not be parsed. You might need to enable internationalized domain name support for class System.Uri. See help of class 
System.Uri for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to check if the users are present or not in a "domain". Why are you using "Servers.txt" - does that contain domain info or server info?

Comment: domain names. Searching to see if users have accounts in domains that are in scope, I should really change that to domain list. Need more coffee, good call!

Comment: This is a starting point:
`$domains = Get-Content .\domain.txt
$names = Get-Content .\users.txt

foreach ($domain in $domains) {

    foreach ($name in $names) {
        
        $user = Get-Aduser -filter "name -like *$name*" -searchbase "DC=$domain,DC=com"

    }

}`
Further, as soon as you get $user, store it into a CSV. Append the  CSV for each iteration. I do not have a set-up for the working domains and users, so I could not come up with a 100% working solution. However, the code I mentioned must be useful to you.